# How do i create a NSOutline programatically without using interface builder? I think I have implemented every steps for creating this

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsoutlineview

I am currently working on a macOS AppKit application and trying to implement an NSOutlineView with custom data using NSOutlineViewDataSource and NSOutlineViewDelegate. However, despite implementing the necessary methods, I am facing an issue where the outline view is not populating with data.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

My Entire Code along with custom implementation:

```
class OutlineViewController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    // MARK: - Properties
    private var outlineView: NSOutlineView!
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rootNode = Node(name: "Root Node")
        let childNode1 = Node(name: "Child Node 1")
        let childNode2 = Node(name: "Child Node 2")
        rootNode.addChild(childNode1)
        rootNode.addChild(childNode2)
    }
    override func loadView() {
        view = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (NSScreen.main?.frame.width)!, height: (NSScreen.main?.frame.height)!)) // Set some default values

        // Create an outline view
        outlineView = NSOutlineView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (NSScreen.main?.frame.width)!, height: (NSScreen.main?.frame.height)!))

        // Register the OutlineCell

        // Set default row height
        outlineView.rowHeight = 50

        // Set the outline view's delegate and data source
        outlineView.delegate = self
        outlineView.dataSource = self

        // Reload the outline view
        outlineView.reloadData()

        let scrollview = NSScrollView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600))
        scrollview.documentView = outlineView
        view.addSubview(scrollview)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            outlineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.topAnchor),
            outlineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.bottomAnchor),
            outlineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.leadingAnchor),
            outlineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    // MARK: - NSOutlineViewDataSource

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        if let item = item as? Node {
            return item.children[index]
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        if let item = item as? Node {
                    return item.children.count > 0
                } else {
                    return false
                }
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        if let item = item as? Node {
            return item.children.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    // MARK: - NSOutlineViewDelegate

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        guard let cell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: TableCellView.identifier), owner: self) as? TableCellView else {
            let cell =  TableCellView()
            cell.profileImage.image = NSImage(named: "boy")
            cell.identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(TableCellView.identifier)
            cell.label.stringValue = "BOY"
            return cell
        }
        cell.profileImage.image = NSImage(named: "girl")
        cell.label.stringValue = "GIRL"
        return cell

    }


}
}

class Node {

    let name: String
    var children: [Node] = []

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func addChild(_ child: Node) {
        children.append(child)
    }
}

class TableCellView: NSTableCellView {
    
    static var identifier =  "TableCell"
    
    var profileImage = NSImageView()
    var label = NSTextField(labelWithString: "")
    
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        addSubview(profileImage)
        addSubview(label)
        profileImage.wantsLayer = true
        profileImage.animates = true
        profileImage.layer?.cornerRadius = 45
        label.isEditable = false
        label.alignment = .center
        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        profileImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 50),
            profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
            profileImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        ])
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImage.trailingAnchor),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 55),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I am only getting empty scroll view.

Comment: You're adding constraints between the outline view and the scroll view. This way the outline view can't scroll and the scroll view doesn't resize with its superview. Add constraints between the view and the scroll view instead.

Comment: Will change it and let you know

Comment: The constraints are not the cause of the issue, rootNode isn't used and the outline view doesn't have any columns.

Comment: I have changed the value in the outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any function. theoretically it should be added to the view now right?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. The outline view doesn't have any columns.

```
outlineView.addTableColumn(NSTableColumn(identifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: TableCellView.identifier)))
```

and at the end of `loadView()`:

```
outlineView.sizeLastColumnToFit()
```

2. You're not using `rootNode` anywhere. In the data source methods, if `item` is `nil` then the item is the root object.

```
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
    if let item = item as? Node {
        return item.children[index]
    } else {
        return rootNode.children[index]
    }
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
    if let item = item as? Node {
        return item.children.count > 0
    } else {
        return rootNode.children.count > 0
    }
}

func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
    if let item = item as? Node {
        return item.children.count
    } else {
        return rootNode.children.count
    }
}
```

3. `viewDidLoad` is called after `loadView` so `reloadData()` is called before `rootNode` is populated. Call `reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad()`.
4. The contraints of `TableCellView` need some work.